What's the use of Resample option in Export dialogue?
In Affinity Designer, I have to export a gradient like this in PNG format, for a brush.

And in export dialogue, I see these Resample options:

But I don't understand the need of it when I'm using a vector program. Does it make any difference in the quality of image I'm exporting?
One relevant quote I found is this:

The best choice of algorithm will depend on the type of image, and
whether you’re enlarging or shrinking it: Lanczos is generally a
better choice when enlarging an image. Lanczos (non-separable)
produces a sharper result than Lanczos (separable), sometimes too
sharp!

I assume it's only used when you're resizing an image that is already exported (e.g., PNG, JPG etc.). For example, I export my gradient image as gradient.png and later import it again and resize it and then export it again, at that moment the Resample option you choose would affect its quality.
Since I'll be using this as a brush for vector strokes and later export a pattern created by lot of strokes, I guess it will involve a lot of resizing of this brush/gradient. So, I wonder if Resample would matter there.

Since it says "whether you’re enlarging or shrinking it", then if you are not doing that to an existing raster image, it probably makes no difference. Exporting a vector to a raster format doesn't typically involve resampling. Exporting a raster image to a different size will involve resampling.

The resampling doesn't only occur when resizing an image that is already exported; resampling happens as soon as the output is a rasterized image.
To understand why, consider an artwork with a color gradient that would be rasterized in an image of 1 pixel. Juste like in this picture, one could imagine several possibilities to perform the rasterization. The color of the resulting pixel could be chosen as

the color at the center of the artboard (white),
or the color that is the most visible (black),
or some average of both (grey):


Now, if the number of pixels increases, the artwork can be partitioned into a grid of smaller artworks, each of those being rasterized to give one pixel. So this brings us to the exact same issue as above! (Note that more realistic sampling methods like bicubic interpolation also use the colors from the surroundings.)

Of course, when more pixels are added, the color sampling for each pixel becomes more and more accurate. This is why in the limit of an infinite resolution, the rasterization faithfully reproduces the vector image. But at any finite resolution, even with thousands of pixels, one has to choose how each pixel will be given a specific color. The example above illustrates that there is not only one way to do this resampling, even if the input comes from a vector program.
